# Navigation to the Android Studio Tools on Welcome Screen

Tags: android-studio

I am sort of lost on where to find the Tools Menu in Android Studio.

According to this link https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds.html, I do not have to run an Android Studio project in order to launch the AVD Manager.

Currently, I am on Android Studio Version 3.0 Beta 6.

I would like some guidance on where the Tools Menu is located in which the link above mentions. Pictures would really help and are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

While you do not have to run a project to access the AVD manager, you cannot access it in the welcome screen. You must first create or open a project and then you should be able to find what the link is referring to.

Comment: I just realized I made a major facepalm, I forgot the difference between running a project and creating a project. I thought running a project was the same thing as a creating a project. Thank you for your answer.